# HashMap<UUID,ArrayList<>>, arraylist won't store values

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, bukkit

I have a hashmap of type HashMap`<UUID,ArrayList<util.Package>>`. The hashmap works fine, but the ArrayList doesn't store. I can add items to it but they do not persist there.

util.Package is an enum type with a couple of Enums within.

I've tried different ways of adding (Straight thru the map: `hashMapName.get(uuid).add(util.Package.TYPE)`, and by getting the object, removing it from the map, adding to it, then putting it back.) Neither has worked.

join event: 
`loadAndCoins.newPlayer(e.getPlayer().getUniqueId());`

loadAndCoins.newPlayer():

```
public static boolean newPlayer(UUID uuid) {
    if (!balances.containsKey(uuid)) {
        balances.put(uuid, 0);
        experience.put(uuid, 
        GameStats.createNewPlayer(uuid);
        Packages.newPlayer(uuid); // this is the line that creates  
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Packages.newPlayer():

```
public static void newPlayer(UUID uuid) {
    ArrayList<util.Package> n = new ArrayList<util.Package>();
    n.add(util.Package.JMSG_DEFAULT);
    System.out.println("NEW: " + n); // debug, has JMSG_DEFAULT
    Packs.put(uuid, n);
}
```

Packages.addPackage(): (Add a package to a uuid)

```
public static boolean addPackage(UUID uuid,util.Package pack) {
    if (!Packs.containsKey(uuid)) return false;
    if (!Packs.get(uuid).contains(pack)) {
        ArrayList<util.Package> op = Packs.get(uuid);
        op.add(pack);
        Packs.remove(uuid);
        Packs.put(uuid, op);
        System.out.println("ADDPACKAGE: " + op);  
                    // has DEFAULT and the added package
        return true;
    } return false;
}
```

Packages.hasPackage(): (Used to check if a uuid has a package)

```
public static boolean hasPackage(UUID uuid,util.Package pack) {
    if (!Packs.containsKey(uuid)) return false;
    System.out.println(Packs.toString()); //has only DEFAULT.
    if(Packs.get(uuid).contains(pack)) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Expected:
First calling addPackage(uuid, Package.JMSG_FESTIVE), 
then calling hasPackage(uuid, Package.JMSG_FESTIVE)
would return true.
Actual: It returns false. The returns of the debug prints are commented, so they are easily understandable.

Contents of util.Package:

```
package util;

public enum Package {
LUCK_1,LUCK_2,LUCK_3,LUCK_4,LUCK_5,SPEED_1,SPEED_2,SPEED_3,SPEED_4,SPEED_5,J
MSG_DEFAULT, JMSG_COMPUTERSPEAK, JMSG_RAINBOW, JMSG_ROYALTY, 
JMSG_FESTIVE,SHOVEL_STONE,SHOVEL_IRON,SHOVEL_GOLD,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is works fine for me:

```
public final class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) { //Just for testing
        final UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        newPlayer(uuid);

        addPackage(uuid, Package.LUCK_1);
        addPackage(uuid, Package.LUCK_2);

        System.out.println(hasPackage(uuid, Package.LUCK_1));
        System.out.println(hasPackage(uuid, Package.LUCK_2));
        System.out.println(hasPackage(uuid, Package.LUCK_3));

        System.out.println(PACKAGE_MAP.toString());
    }

    private static final Map<UUID, List<Package>> PACKAGE_MAP = new HashMap<>();

    public static void newPlayer(UUID uuid) {
        List<Package> n = new ArrayList<>();
        n.add(Package.JMSG_DEFAULT);
        PACKAGE_MAP.put(uuid, n);
    }

    public static boolean addPackage(UUID uuid, Package pack) {
        if (!PACKAGE_MAP.containsKey(uuid)) return false;

        if (!PACKAGE_MAP.get(uuid).contains(pack)) {
            List<Package> op = PACKAGE_MAP.get(uuid);
            op.add(pack);
            //removed `remove` and `put` here.
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean hasPackage(UUID uuid, Package pack) {
        if (!PACKAGE_MAP.containsKey(uuid)) return false;
        return PACKAGE_MAP.get(uuid).contains(pack);
    }
}
```

Package class

```
public enum Package {
    LUCK_1,
    LUCK_2,
    LUCK_3,
    LUCK_4,
    LUCK_5,
    SPEED_1,
    SPEED_2,
    SPEED_3,
    SPEED_4,
    SPEED_5,
    JMSG_DEFAULT,
    JMSG_COMPUTERSPEAK,
    JMSG_RAINBOW,
    JMSG_ROYALTY,
    JMSG_FESTIVE,
    SHOVEL_STONE,
    SHOVEL_IRON,
    SHOVEL_GOLD
}
```

Output:

> true
>
> true
>
> false
>
> {55fc709a-7a25-45e6-9ff2-b48345747d39=[JMSG_DEFAULT, LUCK_1, LUCK_2]}

Some notes for that: you don't need to remove and one more time put the `List` into the `Map` if you modify the `List` while it references to the `List` inside of the `Map`.

Comment: Would the fact I'm using an ArrayList as opposed to a List (with your example) make a difference? That's the only difference I can see since I've tried modifying the arraylist inside the map too.

Comment: Edit: Just figured out what was going on. Turns out it had nothing to do with the methods here, instead the way I was calling addPackage twice based on the result of a hasPackage. This was a novice mistake.